# C++ STL iterator interface

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I know that the STL library uses different kind of iterators to traverse his containers: input, output, forward, bidirectional and random access.

I also know that iterators abstact the classic c pointer interface. So an iterator class must have the ++, * operators and so on (to act like a pointer).

Is the interface for every kind of iterator written in some specification?
Is this interface just a convention used in the STL library or is there some hierarchy of classes from which I should extend my iterators?

From what I understand, I should just 'copy' the interface conventions followed in the STL library to be able to use my iterators with it.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to write anything (e.g. vector's iterator is just a pointer), or you may have to write a lot. If you write your own iterator, you write it from scratch, and it's very noisy. You have to make sure that your iterator is properly tagged; see the documentation of `std::iterator_traits`. There's a Boost library, "iterator facade", that makes it a little easier to write iterators.

Comment: @KerrekSB: +1 but why didn't you put as an answer?

Comment: @Bathsheba: I don't actually want to have to explain all the details and be held accountable... there's just so much noise, which is worth getting right, but never interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can lookup each iterator category interface requirements from [iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) page.

As already mentioned, people often don't bother implementing the entire iterator interfaces from scratch, but use [boost::iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) library for taking care of the boilerplate code.