# iterator categories in c++

Tags: c++, interface, iterator, categories

On [this site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) it is said about iterator categories:

> Instead of being defined by specific types, each category of iterator is defined by the operations that can be performed on it. This definition means that any type that supports the necessary operations can be used as an iterator

Is/can this somehow be enforced (similar to java's interfaces that must be implemented) before runtime?

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361510/c-stl-iterator-interface).

Comment: Probably with concepts in C++17 it can be partially enforced. However there is no practical way to enforce a complexity requirement.

Comment: If you pass something to some function template that requires some operation to be valid, and said thing doesn't support said operation, then the template simply will not compile.

Answer (score 3):

Anything can declare itself as an iterator of a particular category, without implementing all the required methods.

How is it enforced? Very simple. If you then try to use this category with a method or function that makes use of the category-specific operators, since they're not defined, you get a compilation error. The compiler enforces it.

But the practical use of iterator categories is exactly backwards. A template assumes that an iterator that identifies itself as a particular category fully implements the requirements, and uses the iterator's category to verify what kind of an iterator it is, and force a compilation error otherwise.

For example (just off the top of my head), say you want your template function to be used only with random access iterators:

```
template<typename iterator_category> class must_be_random_access_iterator;

template<> class must_be_random_access_iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag> {
public:
    typedef int or_else;
};


template<typename iter_type> void some_func(iter_type iter)
{
    typedef must_be_random_access_iterator<
         typename std::iterator_traits<iter_type>::iterator_category
    >::or_else or_else;

    // ... more code
}
```

The `must_be_random_access_iterator` template is specialized for the `std::random_access_iterator_tag` category, otherwise it is undefined, so passing some other iterator type to the template function will result in a compilation error.

Another, less common, and more complicated approach, is to use specialization or [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) to provide different implementations of the same template class or method that depends on the iterator parameter's category.